# Conditional validation in FluentValidation / switch like

Tags: c#, switch-statement, fluentvalidation

I need some type of conditional validation in FluetValidation, like a switch statement. I've seen there is `When` and `Otherwise` in FluentValidation, but that would give me roughly 10 or more nested `When`/`Otherwise` expressions. Is there any alternative to that?

Update: In pseudocode I need something like this:

```
switch field
    case "A":
        RuleFor(...)
        RuleFor(...)
    case "B":
        RuleFor(...)
        RuleFor(...)
    // ... and so on
    default:
        // add error for the field value ("unexpected value")
```

**Update:**

I was asked to give more details of the "real thing", so:
I receive a rather complex CSV file (50+ columns) - CSV reading is not the issue here, assume it's already read in a collection of typed objects (one row = one object, that's the T in AbstractValidator in FluentValidation). There are actually two columns in the CSV, that are some kind of discriminator. Let's reduce the example to one column discriminator and call this column "discriminator1". If "discriminator1" is equal to "kindA", then 20 out of the 50 columns are expected to be empty and not further processed. However, there are multiple different values for "discriminator1" and on each value it changes which other columns might be empty. So I want to make a switch over "discriminiator1" and in each case I want to check the values of the other columns (or for FluentValidation: of the other properties). Note that

- I want single errors for each column not matching the expectation of being empty or not
- The switch over the "discriminator1" values should have some kind of default case that adds an error to the FluentValidation errors in case the value of "discriminator1" isn't yet known (=not yet handled in the normal switch case expressions).

I want to validate these things so I am not ignoring data (=column values which are not empty anymore) which maybe at a later point in time will be included.

**Update 2:**

With a custom validator, I have this code now:

```
    RuleFor(x => x.Field).Custom((field, context) =>
    {
        switch (field)
        {
            case "typeA":
                // add RuleFor rules
                break;

            case "typeB":
                // add RuleFor rules
                break;

            default:
                context.AddFailure("Unexpected value for field");
                break;
        }
    });
```

The issue I have with that is that `WithState(..)` is not available on the return type of the `Custom(..)` method. So, how to add state? I need this because I have thousands of lines (objects) that are checked and I want to use state so it's clear which line is affected.

Comment: Can you give an example closer to the real thing? As is, I'd assume you'll need a [custom validation](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/custom-validators.html#writing-a-custom-validator).

Comment: @Fildor Thanks for your comment. I added more information as you asked for.

Comment: After edit: I think we could tinker something with [RuleSet](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/rulesets.html)s ... you can define them  and then just select them depending on the value of the discriminator column(s).

Comment: @Fildor I had time to look on this today and went with the custom validation first. It seems to offer the things I need: mix freely pure C# code (e.g. the switch statement) while having access to the validation context to add errors. However, I was unable to combine this with `WithState`. Do you have any idea on that?

Comment: @Fildor Also updated my post with the sample code I have now.

Comment: why not filter your `RuleFor` with `When(...)`?

Comment: @DanielA.White `When` could replace the `case` of a switch, but not the `default` case of a switch to my understanding?

Comment: you would have to negate it that is true